# Как включить миграцию в EF7 в VS2015 ASP.NET5 ответ

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core

Всем доброго времени суток, это не столько вопрос, сколько ответ. Поскольку сегодня потратил N количество времени на поиск ответа.
И так простая команда

```
eneble-migration
```

превратилась в текстовый квест с картинками.

Поскольку от обновления к обновлению задание меняется на сегодня правила прохождения, следующие:
1.  На данные момент никакие пакеты устанавливать не надо, они все есть в решении. Попытка что-то поставить приводило только к ухудшению ситуации. За миграцию отвечает вот этот пакет

```
EntityFramework.Commands (7.0.0-rc1-final)
```

2. В командной строке вводим

   dnx

– вот тут у меня начался квест, если вы в строке увидели ответ, то можете переходить к следующему шагу.
Если нет, то закрываем все окна VS2015 и удаляем папку
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME.dnx

Открываем VS2015 и создаем новый проект и закрываем VS2015, в Powershell в водим навигацию
    cd\
    cd users\YOURUSERNAME.dnx\bin 
и команду 
    .\dnvm upgrade

Если вы получите сообщение об ошибке «Что выполнение скриптов отключено в этой системе.
ТО надо выполнить следующею команду что бы получить разрешение

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Открываем VS2015 и проверяем в командной строке

```
dnx
```

Если вы видите ответ, то первый этап пройден.

3. Дальше нам надо перебраться в командной строке в папку -

cd src\MyProject

```
dnx ef
```

– где командой проверяем что у нас все работает правильно, если все Ок, то мы увидим Единорога.
И введя команду

```
dnx ef migrations –- help
```

мы увидим все возможные варианты развития сюжетной линии дальше.

Данное решение было взято вот из этих двух ответов [основное](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851344/how-can-i-do-an-entity-framework-migration-with-visual-studio-2015-nuget-prompt#_=_)
[, переходы и команды](http://www.bricelam.net/2014/09/14/migrations-on-k.html)

Comment: Может стоит оформить как *вопрос* - *Как включить миграцию в EF7(например)*/*ответ* - получить заслуженную награду в виде кармы, так же мне кажется что метка [tag:entity-framework-7] была бы более уместна